# javascript unable to set property selectindex list box

Tags: javascript, asp.net, listbox, selectedindex

I have a list box which is binding in code behind, the user can select from the list and submit. The error that is occurring in the link button which clear this list from selecting is `unable to set property 'selectedindex' of undefined or null reference`

ASP.NET:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lstBoxAgents" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>

<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkClearAgents" runat="server" 
 OnClientClick="document.getElementById('lstBoxAgents').selectedIndex = -1;return false;">
Clear Me</asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Client ID of the ASP control is not necessarily the same as the ID you give it.  ASP.NET prefixes your controls so that they don't collide, producing a Client ID.  You can check what this ID is by opening your page in a browser and inspecting the element in F12 dev tools.

It is possible to change the ClientID mode using the [ClientIDMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) property.  If you set this to static, the client ID will always be the one you assign and you must ensure uniqueness yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Your listbox has the attribute runat = "server", because of which its id generated is different than the one you have written. So simply check the id being generated at client browser in Chrome's console and specify that id.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkClearAgents" runat="server" 
 OnClientClick="document.getElementById('youridatclientbrowser').selectedIndex = -1;return false;">
Clear Me</asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access your asp.net listbox control ID in javascript as below.

```
document.getElementById('<%=lstBoxAgents.ClientID%>')
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it gave me the same error. Is there a way better than ClientIDMode?